# Is Queue.SyncRoot required for simple Enqueue/Dequeue across threads?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, thread-safety, queue

I have a `WorkerThread` that does a job on elements in the queue and several `MiningThread`s that create stuff need to be done by the `WorkerThread`.

To sum up: One thread Dequeues and several Enqueue.

Do I need to use the sync pattern proposed in msdn or I am thread safe in this specific scenario?

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.syncroot.aspx) a simple sync-access pattern

```
Queue myCollection = new Queue();
lock(myCollection.SyncRoot)
{
    foreach (object item in myCollection)
    {
        // Insert your code here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to sync.

There is a .NET4 queue where you would not need to sync, called "ConcurrentQueue":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

but you would have to migrate to .NET4, until then, you are stuck with doing sync yourself

**Update:**
For your specific pattern, there is even a more specialised class available in .NET4, the BlockingCollection which embraces the Producer/Consumer pattern:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

still .NET4 tough... :)

Comment: Yes you do need to synchronise.

Answer (score 1):

`Queue` is not said to be thread-safe, so you can't just use it in a multithreaded application. You can use the `SyncRoot` property or [Synchronized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized.aspx) method to implement synchronization.